# Multiplying two inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Suppose we have two inequalities
$$a\leq x\leq b\tag{1}$$
$$c\leq y\leq d\tag{2},$$
where $a,b,c,d>0$. Then can I conclude that
$$ac\leq xy\leq bd\quad ?$$

**My attempt:** Since $a,b,c,d>0$ and $\log_e$ is monotonic then we can write
$$\log a\leq \log x\leq\log b\tag{3}$$
$$\log c\leq \log y\leq\log d\tag{4}$$
Adding $(3)$ and $(4)$,
$$\log a+\log c\leq \log x + \log y\leq \log b+\log d.$$
Combining logs gives
$$\log(ac)\leq \log(xy)\leq \log(bd).$$
Exponentiating then gives
$$ac\leq xy\leq bd.$$

Comment: From a fundamental analysis point of view:
If $a,b,c,d$ are all real and all positive and your equations 1, 2 are assumed then according to the properties of $\mathbb{R}$ being an ordered field, along with transitivity that comes from the defining notions of a linear ordering, your conclusion is automatically valid. This is definition 1.17 of Rudin and the following proposition 1.18.

Comment: You can also use that $\frac{b}{x} \geq 1$, $\frac{d}{y} \geq 1$ and that multiplying numbers $\geq 1$ leads to number that is also $\geq 1$ without resorting to logarithms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes your proof is correct. Excellent work reducing the question about multiplying inequalities to a more familiar one of adding inequalities. The only thing I would mention is that taking logarithms and exponentiating are monotone *increasing* operations. If they were monotone decreasing, the inequalities would flip.

Answer (score 0):

In generally, if you have

$$a \leq x \leq b$$

$$c \leq y \leq d$$

with $a,b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ you have that

$$xy \in [\min(ac, ad, bc), \max(bd, ad, cb)]$$

Comment: Not in general. What about the case where $a=-3, b=-1, c=-3, d=-1$ and $x=y=-2$? We obtain the wrong answer $4\in(3,3)$... You should add that $a, b, c, d \in\mathbb{R}^+$ (ie. are positive or null)

Comment: @T.L, good point, you are right.