# How to divide two inequalities in the form $a - \epsilon < x < a + \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds

I have the following inequalities
$$
a - \epsilon_x < x < a + \epsilon_x \\
b - \epsilon_y < y < b + \epsilon_y
$$
with $x,y,a,b,\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y\in {\rm I\!R}$, $|\epsilon_x|>0$ and $|\epsilon_y|>0$.

**How to bound $\frac{x}{y}$?**

---

I first tried to inverse the second inequality
$$
\frac{1}{b + \epsilon_y} < \frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{b - \epsilon_y}
$$
I am not sure if it is correct, but I then used [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3737040/559641) to obtain
$$
\min\left( \frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y}, \frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y}, \frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y} \right) < \frac{x}{y} < \max\left( \frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y}, \frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y}, \frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y} \right)
$$
Can I conclude that
$$
\frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y}
$$
or should I detail every special cases depending on the sign of $a$, $b$... ?

---

I assume that $0\notin(b-\epsilon_y, b+\epsilon_y)$.
I tried to detail the four cases

1. if $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ then $\frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y}$
2. if $a > 0$ and $b < 0$ then $\frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y}$
3. if $a < 0$ and $b > 0$ then $\frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y}$
4. if $a < 0$ and $b < 0$ then $\frac{a+\epsilon_x}{b-\epsilon_y} < \frac{x}{y} < \frac{a-\epsilon_x}{b+\epsilon_y}$

But it seems different from @mathcounterexamples.net 's answer ([see below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3982554/559641)).

Comment: Do you assume that $a-\epsilon_x>0$ and $b-\epsilon_y>0$?

Comment: No I don't have such hypothesis.

Comment: What is the motivation to work on such a general case? Or do you just want to prove something related?

Comment: I simplified at the most my problem to avoid unnecessary symbols.
I am analyzing the rate of convergence of $x/y$ coming from a least-squares regression when the epsilons asymptotically tend toward zero.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you have any assumptions on $x$ and $y$? (Well, you certainly need $y\ne 0$.)

Comment: Yes I only assume that $y \neq 0$, and that $\epsilon_y$ is so small that $0\notin(b-\epsilon_y, b+\epsilon_y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 \in (b- \epsilon_y, b + \epsilon_y)$, there is no way to bound $\frac{x}{y}$.

Otherwise you have $$\vert y \vert \gt m = \begin{cases}
b-\epsilon_y & \text{ if } b - \epsilon_y \gt 0\\
-(b + \epsilon_y) & \text{ if } b + \epsilon_y\lt 0
\end{cases}$$As $\vert x \vert \lt \vert a \vert + \epsilon_x$, you get

$$\left\vert \frac{x}{y} \right\vert \lt \frac{\vert a \vert + \epsilon_x}{m}.$$

Comment: Do you know what is the difference with what I have obtained when I detail the cases depending on signs? (see the edit of my question)

Comment: There are different. Your inequalities are more precise than mine. Mine are easier to write... A question of choice!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would assume that the epsilons are small enough not to make the sums and differences cross zero.  You need to specify that in your answer.  Then, yes, you do need to worry about the signs of $a,b$.  Your result is correct if they are both positive but not otherwise.  For most purposes you are interested in bounding the absolute value of $\frac xy$.  If that is true, you can just take absolute values of $a,b$ and be done.